# How to access a postgresql defined variable from Python

Tags: python, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a python3 code, where I'm inserting data into a postgres table, where the table has a SERIAL integer column, whose value I would like to return after insert.

I have tried using 'Returning', but did not get the ID returned in response

```
query = INSERT INTO table ({{table_columns}}) VALUES ({{table_values}}) RETURNING id;
response = cur.execute(query)
```

Found help in using `into` but that was still returning nothing, also tried selecting the defined variable value.

```
DO $$
DECLARE tableId integer;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table ({{table_columns}}) VALUES ({{table_values}}) RETURNING id INTO tableId;
  SELECT tableId;
END $$;
```

This threw an error.

```
response = cur.execute(query)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: query has no destination for result data
HINT: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at SQL statement
```

How to access the value returned in `tableId` outside from Python after query execution ? Any other alternative solution of returning the `id` value is also welcome.

Postgres Version 11.2

Comment: A `DO` black can not return anything. You will need to wrap your INSERT into a function if you want to do that.

Comment: The error is due to this; ` SELECT tableId;`. That would need to be `PERFORM tableid` to make `plpgsql` happy. It is not going to solve the issue of `DO` blocks not returning anything. Also in a regular function it would not help either as you would not actually be returning the value. That would require `RETURN tableId;` and the correct `RETURNS ` at the top of the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the `id` using `RETURNING`, call the cursor's `fetchone` or `fetchall` method* after executing** the statement.

```
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='test')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("""create table t04 (id serial, name varchar)""")
>>> conn.commit()
>>> cur.execute("""insert into t04 (name) values ('Alice') returning id""")
>>> cur.fetchone()
(1,)
```

---

* `fetchone` returns a tuple, `fetchall` returns a list of tuples.

** `returning` doesn't work with `cursor.executemany`, for psycopg2 at least.  However pyscopg2's `executemany` is no more efficient that calling `execute` multiple times, so just call `execute`.

Comment: If there is another record inserted (from another thread) between the time of execute() and fetchone(), will it fetch the correct id value or the latest id value ?

Comment: I did a basic test using a single connection and cursors in separate threads.  Both cursors reported the correct `returning` value. Obviously I'd encourage you to do your own testing if you want to rely on this behaviour in a production system.